# find the Shortest Path between all the vertices in a graph without giving start or end points

Tags: matlab, graph, artificial-intelligence, shortest-path

i know about the traveling salesman problem, but is there any other algorithm/problem which better fits my needs/description? I need to describe my problem with the help of such a mathematical description.

I have a set of nodes with known start- and endpoint. So i just need to calculate the shortest way to visit all the three points between that two. Dijkstra and similar algorithms try to find the shortest path between two points, so here they probably won´t visit all points between. Or is there a algorithm which finds shortest way and visit all points between two points?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using *Ant colony optimization algorithms*. Refer [Ant colony optimization algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms).

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of the general case of your problem is at least as high as for the Travelling Salesman problem. Just imagine the case where your two endpoints are basically in the same position, then your problem becomes equivalent to the Travelling Salesman.

If you never expect more than five points in your graph though, do you really need to bother with fancy algorithms? You could just do an exhaustive search for the best solution. Since the only decision is the order in which you visit the three points in the middle, you will only have to test 3! = 6 different paths. Even if I misunderstand you and you want the overall shortest open path that visits all nodes, that would still only be 5! = 120 different paths to test (60 if distances are the same in both directions).

Comment: Differently. Your question explicitly stated "I have up to five points with known start- and endpoint." I don't know how to solve the larger problem efficiently, but Visruth's answer looks like a good lead.